# Why am I unable to edit users privileges in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just created this brand new database (MySQL 5.6 on Windows) and created a new admin user but now I can't modify any of the users privileges.  I can click the Add Account button (notice there's one called "newuser") but then I can't set any of the privileges for this new user as everything is disabled, and no matter what user I select, everything is disabled.  I can't even click on the other tabs.

Notice also that even though I have the "admin" user selected there is no Login Name displayed on the Login tab.  It's all blank, like I haven't selected any user at all.

[image]

[image]

I've tried restarting the MySQL service, but that didn't help.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there's a bug in MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 which does not allow it to play nice with MySQL 5.6.  The solution in my case was to uninstall MySQL Workbench 8 and install MySQL Workbench 6.3 instead.

Comment: This is showing as the version for Ubuntu 16.04. I have a ton of missing dependencies with this version. You're telling me it's 2022, and this still isn't fixed? I'll just use Ansible. At least I know that's reliable.